# Why is a straight-arm recovery in butterfly more efficient but in front-crawl it isn't?

Tags: technique, swimming, freestyle, butterfly

In top level swimming, most butterfly competitors demonstrate a straight-arm recovery above the water, but in front-crawl events it's more usual to see recovery with a high, bent elbow and low hand position. Why is one technique preferred for fly and another for front-crawl given that they could be the same.

Comment: I'm unclear on the the hold, given that this is a question directly related to a specific competitive sport (swimming). As for the answer, it is pretty straightforward - go try and perform a butterfly recovery while bending the arms like freestyle - without coming very high up out of the water (which wastes effort) it just isn't doable. It is, however, the number one error that young swimmers make, since they have worked so hard to have the bent-elbow recovery in freestyle. Note that you can do it in freestyle only because of the upper body rotation that also helps breathing.

Comment: I often do not understand the hold/close of stackexchange in general. I have sometimes argued against it. / I see your point. But I still find it doable if you rotate the shoulder. It might even be more relaxed. Le Clos is doing it.

Comment: I'll have to watch video of Chad. From the Olympics I don't remember it being radically different, at least in the vertical direction. I can see a little bending parallel to the water, depending on the shoulder rotation.

Comment: I see your point. If you don't rotate the shoulders, the forearms would dip into the water unless you rotate the shoulder. / The question also relates to why you bend the arm in freestyle recovery. I think bending in butterfly feels relaxed. (Allows lactic acid to escape???) (And I am the opposite of flexible :) / I also vaguely remember a video with Bob Bowman while coaching Phelps discussing bent arms during fly recovery. Not for "real" fly, but during some drill.

Comment: Regarding the hold/close I now also remember that about a week ago I had one comment on a swimming question removed. I think the comment just disappeared? I never got a motivation for that either.

Comment: @JonCuster https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/641

Comment: @ycc_swe https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/641

Comment: Yeah I don't get why this was closed either. Even reading those meta links is confusing. Swimming is a competitive sport and I would say this question is specifically geared towards understanding why butterfly recovery is taught different to frontcrawl as it pertains to efficiency, therefore speed in competitions. These rules are weird.

Comment: *Swimming* is not a competitive sport any more than *running* is. You can't get Olympic medals for *swimming* - you get them for *100m freestyle* and similar events.

Comment: Agreed but there seems an _extremely_ fine line between what's relevant here versus the physical fitness SE, to the point where I don't see why both exist. In my mind the PE site should be for things like gym training/yoga etc and this site should cover all sports, since that's what it's called

Comment: @Nij - so questions on the technical rules, say differentiating butterfly from breaststroke, would be out since a distance is not mentioned in the rule book? That seems, well, absurd.

Comment: Technical rules and regulations from a specific competition, sure. That's what [tag:rules] is for. This question asks from a context of competition, but there is nothing that actually restricts it to that - an amateur who never races may well notice this fact in their own technique and ask the same question, so it's not strictly a competitive sport question. The scope for Sports SE / PF SE has been reasonably well settled for several years now. The current line is more or less agreed by both communities as the most sensible one, when accounting for everything that may go on each.